# Google Sign In and Google API Client Authorisation iOS Issue (401)

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, google-api, adsense-api

I am trying to use the Objective-C Google API Client with the Google Sign In service so that I can authorise my requests.

I've setup my Google Sign In login view controller so that a user can login and accept the request permissions (scopes) required by the app to function. I am then making a request to the AdSense API using the following code:

```
    GTLServiceAdSense *service = [[GTLServiceAdSense alloc] init];
    service.APIKey = @"API KEY FROM CONSOLE";
    service.apiVersion = @"v1.4";
    [service setAuthorizer:[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer];

    GTLQueryAdSense *query = [GTLQueryAdSense queryForAccountsReportsGenerateWithAccountId:@"ADSENSE PUBLISHER ID" startDate:@"DATE" endDate:@"DATE"];
    [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
           //Deal with response.
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
        }
    }];
```

This code will only be run if a user has signed in successfully through the GIDSignIn process. However the request will always produce an error:

> Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=401 "(Login
>   Required)" UserInfo={error=Login Required,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Login Required),
>   GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x7ff1a4029f80: {message:"Login
>   Required" data:[1] code:401}} 2016-04-04 23:10:44.496

I thought I had set the authorisation settings correctly so I don't understand why the login required message is coming up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you solve this problem?